# Exposing Git environment variables

Tags: git

I want to be able to look at the value of `GIT_QUARANTINE_DIRECTORY` and other environment variables while git is receiving a pack, but `printenv` and using Python to check `os.environ` show none of the git environment variables (not even `GIT_DIR`). I know git runs in its own bash shell but am unsure if that is the reason, and if it is, how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to tell from the outside the variables that git decided to set while it is running.... actually, not just git but any process.

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process